# Define dynamic function in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, dynamic-loading, window-object

I am having `SetUpTest()` method, function name will be generated `on-load` of script by fetching window object.
`testShieldVal.js_name` is variable,

```
testShieldVal = window.testObject || {};

SetUpTest = testShieldVal.js_name+"SetUp";

function SetUpTest() {
  new atoShieldVal.js_name.OnloadCallback(grecaptcha);
}
```

How can I define this function with dynamic name efficiently?

Comment: This seems like an XY problem; the easier solution is to put functions in an object w/ a key.

Comment: What is `atoShieldVal`? What is the data type of `.js_name`?

Comment: @trincot function body can be ignored, I just need function name to be taken dynamically as it changes with change window object.
**`testShieldVal.js_name = "login";`**
Let say, 
`function SetUpTest() {
  return "testing";
}`

Comment: Why not define that function on `testShieldVal`? Like `testShieldVal.setup = function () { return "testing"; };`  Dynamic function names are always a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking to define a function with a dynamic name.

In that case you should add the method to the `window` object using `window[functionName] = function() { ... }`

This results in:

```
testShieldVal = window.testObject || {};

SetUpTest = testShieldVal.js_name+"SetUp";

window[SetUpTest] = function {
  new atoShieldVal.js_name.OnloadCallback(grecaptcha);
}
```

When `window.testObject.js_name` is 'Demo' then Your function can then be called via `DemoSetUp()`. This will automatically look in the `window` object for a method with that name.